# Using ROracle to write large data.frame using dbWriteTable performance improvement

Tags: r, oracle

My specific question is how to increase the write buffer size in ROracle (version 1.1-11) to write a dataframe into an Oracle Table? I can't find a corresponding argument although I see one in dbGetQuery for reading a table.

More generally, are there any other tips/tricks to speed up writing a large dataframe into Oracle using the ROracle package?

Thanks for any help you can provide.